# Least possible polynomial deegree of complex roots

Tags: complex-numbers

What is the least possible deegree of polynomial with real coefficients having roots $2\omega , 2+3\omega , 2+3\omega ^2 , 2-\omega -\omega ^2$

As there are four roots so the deegree should be four but the answer is given as five . how ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde yes they are cube root of unity

Comment: @DietrichBurde the concept of g(x) doesn't make sense

Comment: @DietrichBurde in g(x) we can have more terms such as (x-2) etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The least possible degree of polynomial with real coefficients having these roots is the product of $(x-\alpha)(x-\bar\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ are the given roots, unless $\alpha$ is real, in which case the second factor is omitted.

Since $\bar\omega=\omega^2$ and $1+\omega+\omega^2=0$, the polynomial is
$$
(x-2\omega)(x-2\bar\omega)(x-2-3\omega)(x-2-3\bar\omega)(x-3)
\\=
(x^2+2x+4)(x^2-x+7)(x-3)
\\=
x^5 - 2 x^4 + 6 x^3 - 17 x^2 - 2 x - 84
$$

Comment: great answer lhf

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at the given roots. We see that one of these roots,
$2-\omega -\omega ^2$, is in fact *real*:
$$
2-\omega -\omega ^2 = 3, \quad\mbox{ while }\quad
(x-(2+3\omega))(x-(2+3\omega^2)) = x^2-x+7.
$$

A fourth degree polynomial with the four given roots would have complex coefficients, namely, it's the polynomial
$$
P_4(x) =  (x - 3) ( x - 2\omega ) (x^2 - x + 7). \tag{1}
$$

There exists a $5$th-degree polynomial that has all four given roots and an additional fifth root:
$$
P_5(x) = (x - 3) ( x - 2\omega )( x - 2\bar\omega ) (x^2 - x + 7)
$$
$$
 = x^5 - 2 x^4 + 6 x^3 - 17 x^2 - 2 x - 84. \tag{2}
$$

So the sought-for minimal degree is $5$; the polynomial $(2)$ proves this.

The additional root, $2\bar\omega$, is obtained by complex conjugation of the root $2\omega$ of $P_4(x)$, eq. $(1)$.

Comment: What is that additional root and how you know that root will only satisfy this

Comment: Added info on the additional root to the answer text. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Such a polynomial cannot have degree $4$, because we have, using $1+\omega+\omega^2=0$,
\begin{align}f(x) & =(x-2\omega)(x-(2+3\omega))(x-(2+3\omega^2))(x-(2-\omega-\omega^2))\\
 & =x^4 + 2x^3( - \omega - 2) + 2x^2(4\omega + 5) + x( - 20\omega - 21) + 42\omega,
\end{align}
which does not have real coefficients. Also, no scalar multiple of it has real coefficients.

Comment: so how do we know the deegre 5 will have real coeficient